# New Laptop Battery - should I be concerned about its life?

Tags: battery, charging

My sons laptop battery needed replacing, so I purchased a (ostensibly new, legitimate Dell OEM) battery from a local supplier, however the battery behaved in a way I don't recall seeing before (in fairness, I don't often change laptop batteries).  The battery is a 42Wh  Lithium Polymer battery, Dell code WDX0R.

Immediately when the battery was plugged in the laptop - a 2016 Dell Inspiron - advised the battery was at 48%, however by the time it started and installed Windows updates - 2 or 3 minutes later, the battery level was 7%.   According to the battery report the capacity somehow jumped from 48% (20258mWh) to 7%(2827mWh) when the charger was plugged in.

The battery report tells the story -

[image]

Is this normal for a new battery?  Do I have to calibrate the battery (I would have thought not - and if so, can I do so without draining it below 20%).

Comment: Return the battery. Most likely it’s not legit.

Comment: Second that, sounds like a return to me.

Comment: In addition to the other suggestions, (a) is it plugged into AC while the battery is going down?  and then (b) if so, it may be calibrating.  There should be a Dell battery App to do that.

Comment: @john No.  It jumped down from 48% to 7% immediately the power was plugged in and then charged up to 100% and a second Windows report showed it at very close to 42000 mWh

Comment: @davidgo Also, if the battery dropped from 48% to 7% immediately (as you state) what’s to say it doesn’t do something in the other direction power-wise and damage your son’s PC? Better return it and possibly for a full refund and spend your money elsewhere where the authenticity of the battery can be fully assured.

Comment: To be honest, I think the comments about the battery not being legit are jumping the gun.  Certainly fake batteries are common in some parts of the world, but generally not in New Zealand (except from online auction sites).   The battery details in its self reporting are also consistent with a legitimate battery.   I'm certainly not saying this battery is OK or otherwise yet - just that I dont see any evidence its fake.

Comment: @davidgo “ …comments about the battery not being legit…” How about just calling it a lemon? And letting the seller sort out how to make this good for you. No matter which way you slice it, you are doing everything right; a battery dropping to 41% points for no reason in seconds is not a good thing.